# libGDX: Moving Polygons Across Screen

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Newbie in both game development and libGDX.

I want to move a polygon having 6 vertices across the screen from right to left. once it reaches left, the position is rest to right end and this way it continues. How to do this? I tried the setOrigin and setPosition methods of the libGDX [Polygon](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html)but it isn't showing any change in position.

Edit: This is the way I did

```
  //initializing
  private Polygon polygonSample = new Polygon(new float[]{0, 56, 0, 57, 61, 57, 107, 11, 150, 11, 150, 10, 107, 10, 61, 56});

  //update
  polygonSample.translate(-50.0f, 0.0f);

   //Rendering
   shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Line);
   shapeRenderer.setColor(255 / 255.0f, 109 / 255.0f, 120 / 255.0f, 1);
   shapeRenderer.polygon(polygonSample.getVertices());
   shapeRenderer.end();
```

Comment: Please post some code as well.

Comment: just added the sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

According to [Polygon documentation](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/Polygon.html#getVertices--), `getVertices` method

> Returns the polygon's local vertices without scaling or rotation and without being offset by the polygon position.

---

### Solution

Replace

```
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygonSample.getVertices());
```

with

```
shapeRenderer.polygon(polygonSample.getTransformedVertices());
```

Good luck.